# Date format change from dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy in web server

Tags: c#, date

I am using date range picker calendar for saving dates in database in the format of `dd-mm-yyyy` from C# code and it's saving properly from my local code. But when I am uploading code to web server and checking database date value, it's showing in `mm-dd-yyyy` format.

Can someone please help? is there any setting in web.config

Comment: Don't. Handle them as dates, not strings. Dateformat is a presenting issue not a data storage issue

Comment: ***WHAT*** database? SQL Server for instance doesn't store a date in any string with a format - it's a **8-byte binary** datatype. The display is controlled only by the tool / application used to actually **show** the date value